# VanillaTilt.js destroy tilt in divs

Tags: javascript, plugins

Help please.Have an error in console

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')

```
  if (window.innerWidth > 991.98) {
     VanillaTilt.init(destroyBox, {
        max: 10,
        speed: 10000
     })
  } else {
     destroyBox.vanillaTilt.destroy();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't destroy when never been `init`. That is the fix. However for an ugly workaround you can

```
  if (window.innerWidth > 991.98) {
     destroyBox.vanillaTilt || VanillaTilt.init(destroyBox, {
        max: 10,
        speed: 10000
     })
  } else {
     destroyBox.vanillaTilt && destroyBox.vanillaTilt.destroy();
  }
```

Comment: thanks 
your option suited me, but how to make it not ugly? what do you think

Comment: Is this a `resize` event handler? what is the context? You shouldn't `init` if you already `init` and shouldn't `destroy` if you haven't `init`. So if you don't want to mess with it too much, go for the ugly solution which will work.